# Are there any problem books with solutions for an elementary business statistic course?

Tags: statistics

As my teacher doesn't use any textbooks in the course, I can only depend on the exercises that were given to me. The main reference textbook (which is never discussed at all) that I have for my course doesn't have any solutions in it therefore I can only read it for the theory. There are a lot of questions that I can't answer and check for correctness, therefore I would be really grateful for any recommendations on problem books with solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elementary business statistics: A first course by Russell Robert Johnson

Business Statistics For Dummies
by Alan Anderson

Business Statistics: Problems & Solutions by   $\space $  J K Sharma [Here](https://compress-pdf.bcad.info/)

Probably helps.